# New line character not showing up in Apache Camel Route

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to append lines in apache camel separated by a new line. This is what I am trying:

```
.transform().simple("asda\n")
.to("file:{{file.tempLocation}}?fileName=${header.csvFileName}.txt")
.transform().simple("asda\n")
.to("file:{{file.tempLocation}}?fileName=${header.csvFileName}.txt&fileExist=Append")
.transform().simple("asda\n")
.to("file:{{file.tempLocation}}?fileName=${header.csvFileName}.txt&fileExist=Append")
```

Ideally this should output

```
asda
asda
asda
```

But I am getting `asdaasdaasda` and I cannot figure out why.

I tried changing the line ending separator from CRLF to LF in notepad++ and that doesn't help either.

Comment: Did you try with `.transform().constant("asda\n")`?

Comment: Yep. Doesn't work. Moreover, using constant wont replace dynamic values.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is, you have to use;

```
transform().simple("asda\\n")
```

1. Use `simple()` instead of `constant()`
2. Use `\\n` instead of `\n`

A working example is as follows;

```java
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class TimedFileAppenderRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("timer:java?period=1000")
            .routeId("quartz-route")
            .to("direct:work-route");
        
        from("direct:work-route")
            .routeId("work-route")
            .transform().simple("128 Milyar Nerede!\\n")
            .log("Body: .${body}.")
            .to("file:output/?fileName=test.txt&fileExist=Append");
    }

}
```